# Unauthorized client or scope Google Webmaster Tools API

Tags: .net, api, google-search-console

I have been running in to a problem, the last couple of days, which I seem not to be the only to have.

I am trying to connect to Google Webmaster Tools via the .NET Library provided by Google trough NuGet. I have succesfully created a project in Google Developer Console, generated my Service Account and retrieved a p12-key.

Next thing is to get a list of all sites in Webmaster Tools, which I do by the following:

```
...
var result = webmasterService.Sites.List().Execute();
```

When running the code i get the following error:

```
Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Unauthorized client or scope in request.", Uri:""
```

Now the problems seems to be that my client is not authorized to access the Webmaster Tools ressources. I have been browsing the internet the last couple of days to find help, but I'm stuck with this problem.

Where do I have to specify this users email, to authenticate it properly?

My connector-code is as specified:

```
string keyPath = Server.MapPath("/keys/webmastertoolsapi.p12");
const string serviceAccountEmail = "yadayada-123123@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
const string appName = "WebMasterToolsAPI";

var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyPath,"notasecret",X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        User = "name@domain.com", //email-account which has owner-rights in Webmaster Tools
        Scopes = new[] { WebmastersService.Scope.Webmasters }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

var webmasterService = new WebmastersService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = appName,
});
```

Comment: Exact same issue. Impossible to find a way to make it work, for now.